LetsEncrypt SSL with HAProxy Renew Not Working
I am trying to give SSL on HAProxy using certbot with LetsEncrypt. I am creating SSL with command:
 sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d test.example.com \
    --non-interactive --agree-tos --email admin@example.com \
    --http-01-port=8888

It is creating a new certificate. There is no problem. But If I want to renew the certificate, renewal fails.
When I run sudo certbot renew --dry-run. Giving this error:
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/test.example.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert not due for renewal, but simulating renewal for dry run
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Simulating renewal of an existing certificate for test.example.com
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for test.example.com
Cleaning up challenges
Failed to renew certificate test.example.com with error: Problem binding to port 8888: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.

I am using this source : https://serversforhackers.com/c/letsencrypt-with-haproxy
I am creating my haproxy(HA-Proxy version 2.2.9-2+deb11u6) config like that:
frontend fe-example

    bind *:4433 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/test.example.com/test.example.com.pem

    # New line to test URI to see if its a letsencrypt request
    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl

    default_backend be-example

# LE Backend
backend letsencrypt-backend
    server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888

# Normal (default) Backend
# for web app servers
backend be-example
    # Config omitted here

But this config not work on me.
My first question is; what is wrong in this HAProxy config?
My second question is; is this method for giving SSL certificate true?

Define "can't do it" and "config not working".

@AlexD When I restart the HAProxy, it gives error.

You need to describe exactly what kind of errors you are getting.

@AlexD Ah yes. Thank you for your notice.

Update 
After checked the ports and make sure it is not used I solved this issue with this config:

You should use 80 port because acme challenge is using this port for http challenge. So our config looks like that:

frontend fe-example

    bind *:80
    bind *:4433 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/test.example.com/test.example.com.pem

    # New line to test URI to see if its a letsencrypt request
    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    use_backend letsencrypt-backend if letsencrypt-acl

    default_backend be-example

# LE Backend
backend letsencrypt-backend
    server letsencrypt 127.0.0.1:8888

# Normal (default) Backend
# for web app servers
backend be-example
    # Config omitted here

and then certbot renewals working nicely.
Thank you for your helps.

Error message Problem binding to port 8888: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6. indicates that some application is already listening on port 8888. Check output of sudo ss -plnt | grep 8888 to find out.

Thank you. There was a docker container using the port. But now it gives this error: Failed to renew certificate test.example.com with error: Some challenges have failed.. Could this be related to the 4433 port in the frontend fe-example?
